# How do I add more than one error to the errors array in graphql-ruby?

Tags: ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

The documentation for GraphQl-Ruby states that top level errors are added to `errors` when [raising an exception](https://graphql-ruby.org/errors/execution_errors) like this:

```rb
raise GraphQL::ExecutionError, "Can't continue with this query"
```

Which produces:

```rb
{
  "errors" => [
    {
      "message" => "Can't continue with this query",
      "locations" => [
        {
          "line" => 2,
          "column" => 10,
        }
      ],
      "path" => ["user", "login"],
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to continue and add more than one error to the errors array. How do I do this (cleanly without a hack)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer somewhere in a `rescue_from` execution (can't remember where).

Basically, you need to push onto `context.errors`. You can do it in a prepare method on your input type or in the field.

Something like this:

```rb
class MyInputObject < GraphQL::Schema::InputObject
  def prepare
    context.errors << GraphQL::ExecutionError.new('bummer!') if bummer?
    context.errors << GraphQL::ExecutionError.new('darn it!') if darn_it?

    super
  end
end
```

For me, the errors were automatically raised and I didn't need to have any `rescue_from` anywhere in my implementation.

You might need to raise an execution error.

This will give you an array of errors as a response. Very useful if your error handling is a little complex.

See:
https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/2.0.0/GraphQL/Schema.html#rescue_from-class_method
https://graphql-ruby.org/api-doc/2.0.0/GraphQL/Query/Context.html